# Displaying Nested Object after Retrieval from API

Tags: javascript, angular, http

Good day all,

I am having some trouble in displaying simple data given an API service containing a NESTED json object.

The reason the "nested" part is giving me trouble in that most tutorials only cover how to display the retrieved data if the data is an array object (and not nested).

The nested object from the api service as such a structure:

```
{
  "students": [
    {
      "city": "Fush\u00eb-Muhurr", 
      "company": "Yadel", 
      "email": "iorton0@imdb.com", 
      "firstName": "Ingaberg", 
      "grades": [
        "78", 
        "100", 
        "92", 
        "86", 
        "89", 
        "88", 
        "91", 
        "87"
      ], 
      "id": "1", 
      "lastName": "Orton", 
      "skill": "Oracle"
    }, 
    {
      "city": "Sanghan", 
      "company": "Avamm", 
      "email": "cboards1@weibo.com", 
      "firstName": "Clarke", 
      "grades": [
        "75", 
        "89", 
        "95", 
        "93", 
        "99", 
        "82", 
        "89", 
        "76"
      ], 
      "id": "2", 
      "lastName": "Boards", 
      "skill": "Sports"
    }]
}
```

to give you a clearer idea, an array object (and one which does NOT give me trouble) is:

```
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "qui est esse",
    "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "ea molestias quasi exercitationem repellat qui ipsa sit aut",
    "body": "et iusto sed quo iure\nvoluptatem occaecati omnis eligendi aut ad\nvoluptatem doloribus vel accusantium quis pariatur\nmolestiae porro eius odio et labore et velit aut"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 4,
    "title": "eum et est occaecati",
    "body": "ullam et saepe reiciendis voluptatem adipisci\nsit amet autem assumenda provident rerum culpa\nquis hic commodi nesciunt rem tenetur doloremque ipsam iure\nquis sunt voluptatem rerum illo velit"
  }]
```

Currently, I am using the following code to get the json object from the API:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

studentsList: any


getData(){
this.studentsList = this.http.get('apiurl.com(not shown)')

}
}
```

as you can see, this is the simplest way that it can be done.  As I understand, getData() returns an "Observable."

Now, here is the tricky part.  How do I display this observable in the html template?  I understand how to use ngFor, but the tricky part is that I have to "access" the nested object contents, in particular the "students" property that would otherwise not be there if it was an array.

For your information, the code to display the array variation (not nested variation) is the following:

```
<button (click) = 'getData()'>Get Data</button>


<div *ngFor = 'let student of studentsList | async'>
{{student | json}}
</div>
```

However, I cannot use the above, as it does not apply to nested objects.

Thinking about this problem, can we convert the returned observable into a simple Javascript object before we even head into the html template?  If that can be done, then accessing the content (and thereby displaying it afterward with ngFor) is trivial.

I tried the JSON.parse and JSON.stringify combinations.  However, that did not help as I believe that the object is already parsed through the get method.

Hopefully, I asked the question properly, and thanks for your help.

Best regards,
Andy

Comment: You should be able to do something like `"let student of (studentsList | async)?.students"` I think.

Comment: hmm, okay.  Thinking about it, is it possible to convert the observable to a plain javascript object within the component template?

Comment: but you are right! @BertMaurau.  Your solution totally works!  Thanks :)

Comment: In addition to usual template approach (answer below) you can always pipe map (RxJS) the http response `this.http.get('apiurl.com(not shown)').pipe(map(apiResponse => apiResponse.students))`. Btw put http requests in a dedicated service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to subscribe to the observable returned from the HTTP call to retrieve it's contents.

```js
getData() {
  this.http.get('apiurl.com(not shown)').subscribe(
    response => {
      this.studentsList = response;
    },
    error => {
      console.error('Error retrieving student properties ', error);
    }
  );
}
```

And in the template you could do the following

```
<div *ngFor='let student of studentsList?.students'>
  {{ student | json }}
</div>
```

`async` pipe is not needed anymore since we are not looping over an observable, but rather over an object.

The `?.` in `studentsList?.students` is the [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths). It guards against accessing `undefined` and `null` values in property paths. It is needed here since till the `getData()` function is called, accessing `studentsList.students` will return `undefined` which will result in an error.

Comment: Thank you so much for this elegant answer.  This is exactly the type of answer that I was looking for.  However, although I can now display the object, the console is showing such an error "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'students' of undefined"
This error doesn't seem to affect the results, which are displayed.  Is this a normal occurence?  Thank you.

Comment: Okay, nevermind, I forgot to write the question mark in.  Now it works error-free.  Thanks again.